# distort curved shape to fit on curved shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, distort

I've read a lot of other answers and tried for hours but I can't get this circle shape to look right on this flag shape

[image]

i think it's because the circle is a curve and so is the flag. If anyone has any experience with this your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Circle looks okay to me - like a folded circle is it supposed to looks different? What is "correct"?.. the bottom of the flag, where it folds is incorrect. That white outline is causing the flag to be percieved more flat and thus throwing off the effect.

Comment: I think @Scott has a point. The thing that is wrong tough is that the circle needs to diminish more in size by 1/8-1/4 since the fold itself uses up material than you seem to be using. Also when you wrap use a circle made out of 8- 12 sections it warps better.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I'll try and section the circle a 12 times and warp it again. Maybe I need to loose the outline too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try 3D effect. This approach may help you understand the form of logo. Four steps:

1. Create texture as a shape
2. Convert it into symbol (drag and drop to symbols panel)
3. Create a curve (flag cross-section)
4. Effects → 3D → Extrude & Bevel → Map Art

[image]